# Web Service get URL user is coming from

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Web Service 4.7.2 Framework where I want to check where the user is coming from. I have tried using `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;` but it is always null is there anything else I can use to see what url the user is using to send the JSON FromBody text to the `IHttpActionResult`.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult SaveRequestForm([FromBody] RequestWeb request)
        {
            try
            {
                //Uri referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
                
    Uri referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
    var referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Comment: On the web application there is a form submit button I wanted to capture that page url information.

Comment: Both `Request.Url` and `Request.RawUrl` is the current page not the UrlReferrer.

Comment: I see what you are asking, sorry my bad. If `UrlReferrer` is null, you could set a hidden input in your Form with the info you needed, `UrlReferrer` is a header usually set by the browser, so I'm not sure why it would be null.